# Low Connectivity on Wireless Xbox 360 Controller for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, xbox360, game-controller

I bought a wireless Xbox 360 controller for my laptop. It seems to work fine when turning it on. However, it will only stay connected within 3 feet range of the receiver. I have a bluetooth USB receiver, a wireless keyboard, and a wireless mouse connected to the same laptop so maybe that's causing interference. But I have tried disconnecting them and still the range is low. Is my product defective or is there interference going on?

Comment: Could you provide links to the exact Xbox accessories that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

The USB receiver for your controller, is it  Microsoft brand or third party? 
I initially bought a third party receiver and I had the same range problem. After using my friend's Microsoft receiver immediately noticed a difference.

Comment: There's an answer here (in that Microsoft-brand products appear better) but as is, it is better as a comment.